# Subtracting values from groups

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a group having 2 different dates. The result that it outputs is like this:

PeriodID-----GroupName-----Value
16-----FUEL-----200
15-----FUEL-----800

Now I want to subtract 200 from 800. and desired result is 600

How Do I subtract these values from same group? any idea?

Comment: you could use the running total using a forumla, and instead of add you subtract. http://crystalreportsblog.com/crystal-reports-running-totals/

Comment: To the extent I understand Date is the first group and inside that date you have the above data now my question is where do you want to display the subtracted result? In date group or somewhere else?

Comment: @Siva Date is the first group, inside that i have product group. In the footer of first group, i have sum for that product for that date. Next i have sum of that same product but different date. I want the difference of both these sums :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

Create a formula and write below code.

```
Evaluateafter(firstproduct<Formula>);
Evaluateafter(Secondproduct<Formula>);

sum(<Product1>,<Dategrouping>)-sum(<Product2>,<Dategrouping>)
```

now you have the end result.

If this doesn't work let me know.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Tell me how to take the product field value for each group, so that i can take difference of that two values.

Comment: @Saad Khatri.. When you insert summary of a filed in detail section then that will be automatically visible in field tree when you got to formula