# How to do subtraction operation in details section

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I create a report and I group data based on bank name.
for each employees we have the following :

```
BANK 1
********
1        2800,00
2        1000,00
---------------------------------
result1  1800,00
---------------------------------
BANk 2
********
1        5700,00
2        4560,00
---------------------------------
result2  1140,00
---------------------------------
TOTAL    2940,00(result1+result2)
---------------------------------
```

in details section of each group I have just two row 
what I want is to do subtraction operation between two rows of each group and show the result.
thank you in advance.

Comment: It's quite hard to advise without seeing the specific RPT, but on first shot - have you added maybe the group section with BANK name or id ?

Comment: ok so results are in group footer and total is in report footer?

Comment: Yes siva the result are in group footer and the total is in report footer but the important thing hère is in each group detail section I have only two rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula to subtract from each other.
For each group , you can set the value record1 and record2 ,and in footer , apply subtraction.

check this link.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Reporting/Crystal_Reports/Q_27952051.html

[how do i subtract two grandtotal fields in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297405/how-do-i-subtract-two-grandtotal-fields-in-crystal-reports)

[Subtracting values from groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392626/subtracting-values-from-groups)

Comment: Thank you ajay2707 but i cant see the content of your Link can you explain me hère the solution thank you in advance

Comment: what I want is to use two variables used in group section and when changed group it reset. for example  variable 1=(row1 :column 1) variable2=(row2:column1) and after that I create a formula =variable2-variable1 and place this variable in group footer